# A good setup for distributed monitoring and tracking latency/drops in a network

Tags: networking, tcp, monitoring, openstack

I want to preface this by saying that I've never taken a networking class but I'm learning on the job. Things like TCP/IP networking I have a pretty basic grasp of and if you think this will hinder my attempt at this let me know.

The task I have at hand is thus: I have an Open Stack network with a bunch of nodes that can communicate with each other, all running CentOS virtual machines (just for simplicity's sake) with applications running on top of them. The task is basically to find a way to monitor the ping of every node and report whenever some kind of message (probably through http) that reports what happened. The logic of checking for the actual latency problems isn't what I'm struggling with, its the best structure to complete this task.

I'm thinking of using Nagios and setting up a **distributed monitoring system**. Basically my plan is to instal nagios on each node after writing my plugin (unless its already offered or exists) and it would simply ping everything else in the network once its setup and the other nodes ping it once the fact that it has joined the network is detected. I'm not sure exactly how scalable this is because if the number of nodes increase a lot would having every node pinging every other node actually be a good thing? Could it actually end up being a lot of stress on the network?

Is this a bad idea? I know a more efficient solution would be something where as long as every node is being checked (not necessarily have to have every node connected to by every other node) is more efficient. Visualizing it as a graph with a couple of points, it would be a bidirectional graph with just one path connecting each point rather than every possible point having edges between each other. But I don't know if this is the level I should be thinking about it or not.

In short, what I'm asking is: How would one go about setting up a ping monitoring system between a bunch of Open Stack nodes?

Let me know if this question makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a mess. There are things like NetFlow and IP SLA to monitor things on a network. By the way, ping only measures latency for ICMP, and that has nothing to do with real network traffic.

Comment: okay, but these are virtual machines that i want to check the latency between, so there aren't any physical routers. also there are "ping-like" tools that basically measure the same thing right? like fping or tcping, etc. why wouldn't you go with nagios in this situation?

Comment: NetFlow and IP SLA have various implementations. Your network between VMs is still using layer-2 and layer-3 networking, and you can use the tools to measure real traffic. That is exactly why these tools were designed. You are simply trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: yeah i could tell that it felt like i was trying to do something that's definitely been done before, the only part that i'm confused about is this: is the monitoring service itself distributed across the network? (each node having a daemon running it) or does it require some host machine to come back to and record everything? I'm assuming the latter, but the issue is that if that host machine goes down there will be a big problem. I think that's the main issue i'm trying to wrap my head around

Comment: thanks for the advice also

Comment: NetFlow and IP SLA use collector hosts. They can be located in more central locations, and there are various applications to collate and produce reports. Depending on the implementation selected, you can have multiple collectors, and they may be able to replicate. This is really something for which you should look for trends, e.g. should you upgrade a particular link, or does something hog your bandwidth at a particular time of day. It's not normally something where missing a couple of hours due to a down host really affects you.

Answer (score -1):

Still not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with this setup, but the Nagios setup you're describing sounds messy and likely won't cover what you need. I'd look at building packetbeat into the provisioning of each of your hosts, and then shipping that data off to Elasticsearch. That way you can watch your actual application-level traffic and response times.  https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/packetbeat

Comment: well the problem has been more clarified. i'm not super concerned with the network traffic so much as i am concerned with just checking the latency between the nodes. basically if there's a poblem (someone complains the network is slow) i just need a way to figure out whether the problem is on their end or ours, in which case pinging the problematic node from somewhere else or in the case of some kind of drop/spike, keeping track of those pings is fine. i'll probably have a centralized host computer keeping the logs. i don't have to deal with the application layer